# Pop!_OS can't upgrade packages due to unconfigured zlib1g

Tags: upgrade, pop-os

Whenever opening the Pop Shop, it freezes and crashes. *Updating* packages through aptitude works, but *upgrading* fails with

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
```

zlib1g appears to be properly installed and `sudo apt install` ultimately triggers the same error:

```
$ sudo apt install zlib1g:i386
[sudo] password for redhand: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu7.1).
zlib1g:i386 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
```

Trying to fix the broken dependency tells me that zlib1g is definitely installed and up to date.

```
$ sudo apt install -f zlib1g
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu7.1).
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What does `sudo apt install zlib1g:i386` say?

Comment: It ultimately leads to the same error. I just updated the question to include that output.

Comment: OK, what about `sudo dpkg --configure zlib1g:i386`?

Comment: That processes a bunch of triggers, then terminates with `Errors were encountered while processing:  zlib1g:amd64`. I'll try to configure `zlib1g:amd64` next.

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` appears to have fixed the problem. The pop shop and `apt upgrade` are both working again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` fixed the problem.

In some cases it may need to be followed by
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`